# How to replace two-way light switches with two black and two red wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I'm in the US/East Coast.

I'm trying to replace my two-way kitchen light switches but I don't understand the wiring.

At switch #1, there are 4 wires that connect to the switch. I get that I need to tie K1-W1 (Kitchen Wire 1 to Workbox Wire 1), K4-W4, and either (K2-W2 & K3-W3) or (K2-W3 & K3-W2) : [image: Switch #1]

But I don't understand the wiring on switch #2:
[image: Switch #2]

One of the black/red pairs must be connected to Switch #1 Workbox's black/red pair, and I can use a multimeter to find out, but how do I connect both pairs of wires to the 4 wires of the second Lutron switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have what is usually referred to as a **4-way switch**.

When there are two switches controlling one light, they are called **3-way switches**. There are a number of ways of wiring them, but basically power comes in to one of the switches on one wire, travels across to the other switch on two wires ("travellers") and then comes out of the second switch on one wire. For important reasons, there are usually three wires making the journey between the switches - the two travellers plus one of:

- Hot
- Switched Hot
- Neutral

However, if you want to have 3 or more separate switches controlling one light, you need *4-way switches*. The first and last switches are 3-way switches and any in-between switches are 4-way switches. Again, there are a bunch of ways of wiring this up. But one method is:

- Hot Black/White Neutral to first switch
- Traveller 1 Black/Traveller 2 Red/Neutral White from first switch (3-way) to second (4-way)
- Traveller 1 Black/Traveller 2 Red/Neutral White from second (4-way) switch to third (3-way) switch.
- Switched Hot Black/White Neutral from third switch to light.

In this example, the white wire will not actually be connected to any of the switches, just chained along in each switch box. And in the middle switch box you will see red/black from each of the other switches attached to the switch, just like in your picture.

The catch is that many smart switches don't work with 4-way switches, so you need to find one that does.

Comment: Obligatory Planet-wide note - in most Commonwealth countries (at least) the USA/Canada  4-way is called 3-way, and the USA/Canada 3-way is called 2-way. But the wiring here looks very USA/Canada, and it's not called a 2-way any place I know of. +1, this comment is just for the sake of our international readers...

Comment: I understand your explanation about 3 and 4 way switches but they don't seem to apply here. There are *only* two switches that control the kitchen lights, that I know of. So one would think they'd be wired in a 3-way config. If so, there should *only* be Black (hot), Red (Traveller 1), Black (Traveller 2), and Ground. But there is *another* red wire.

Comment: (continued comment) So either there is a hidden switch, and I'm looking at one of the "intermediary" switches, or this is not a 4-way.

Comment: A switch with 4 connections (excluding neutral (smart switches) and ground) is, as far as I know, pretty much **always** a 4-way switch. There are some other, much more unusual, types of switches that would have 4 active wires. But in a home in the US/Canada, that pretty much means "4-way" switch in between a pair of 3-way switches. If you really can't find another switch in the circuit then you'll have to start tracing wires.

Comment: Edited: I just found a 3rd switch that controls the kitchen lights. So sorry for the confusion! This is indeed a 4-way configuration. Will update my OP.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the routing of the wiring decides for you where the smart switches are going to be.  You don't get to choose.  Most people get stuck on smart switches when they try to force the choice: "I want to put the master here, and therefore the wiring must cooperate", no, it need not!

This is a 4-way switch, designed to go between two 3-way switches.  (The American terms; -1 for Europe).  This run also looks like a non-switch-loop with power running

```
supply - 3way - 4way (repeating?) - 3way - light
```

Like this, but with the lamp slid all the way to the extreme right past the last switch.

[image]

Of the yellow travelers, one is hot and one is not.   The switches exchange which is hot.  In your wiring, your 2 travelers are actually the red-black pair.

As such, the smart switch master generally must be installed at the rightmost (lightmost lol) 3-way, and remotes installed according to the particular switch's instructions.  Your pictures feature the leftmost 3-way and the 4-way.